# Why is this function expression undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Can someone explain me why this function become undefined when i store it in a variable ?

```
model.where({'artisan.id':id}).count(function(err, doc) {
  console.log(err, doc); // this work
})

var fn = model.where({'artisan.id':id}).count;

console.log(typeof fn); // ==> 'function'

fn(function(err, doc) { // undefined is not a function
      console.log(err, doc); 
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett, if that were true then their console.log of typeof fn would show it as undefined, and their first line wouldn't work either. Abel, Are you sure that is the actual line that the error refers to?

Comment: When i call fn with a 10 seconds timeout, it's still undefined. It seems that it's the callback function that is undefined. But it doesn't make any sens...

Comment: `count` probably expects the value of `this` to refer to  a specific object, not the global object. In general `var foo = obj.foo; foo();` is not equal to `obj.foo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely because you aren't actually calling `count()` as a method.

Assigning `.count` to `fn` only keeps a reference to the `function` itself. It becomes detached from the `model.where({'artisan.id':id})` query object and is later invoked with the default `this` value -- `global` or `undefined`, depending on the use of strict mode.

At some point, it likely tries to reference another method, which won't be available through the default `this`, such as:

```
function count(callback) {
    this.method(...);      // TypeError: undefined is not a function
    // global.method(...);
}
```

One way to resolve this is to [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method, so its `this` value is fixated:

```
var query = model.where({'artisan.id':id});
var fn = query.count.bind(query);

fn(function (...) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is not thrown from the line you said, but internally from the `fn` function because you are executing it using wrong context.

When you say `model.where(...).count(...)` the count function is executed using the value returned from `where()` as its context, but when you `fn(...)` that is not happening instead the function will be executed using the `window` context(`undefined` in strict mode) where it may not be finding some required internal properties resulting in the error

```
var where  = model.where({
    'artisan.id': id
});

var fn = where.count;

console.log(typeof fn); // ==> 'function'

fn.call(where, function (err, doc) { // undefined is not a function
    console.log(err, doc);
})
//or
where.count(function (err, doc) {
    console.log(err, doc); // this work
})
```